# Dumping structure using dbx

Tags: c, debugging, solaris, dbx

I'm debugging my C program using dbx on Solaris, and I'd like to be able to see the contents of a data structure.

It's a local data structure in the function that's in scope, so typing "dump" shows a pointer to the structure.  However, I'd like to look at the contents of various fields within it.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the 'print' command offers the best functionality for this kind of thing.
If your local pointer variable is called 'p', then use "print *p".  The argument to print can be any language expression, for example "print p->buf" or "print p->buf[3]"

Comment: Easy when you know how.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your structure pointer variable is called `struct_ptr`, does this work?

```
dump *struct_ptr
```

Comment: How it works is a mix of both answers.

If you want the address of the pointer, then "print my_struct".

If you want the data of a member then "print my_struct -> member".

If you want to dump the whole structure members and address's then "print *my_struct"